# Is it possible to authenticate with nodered using jwt headers (node-red)

Tags: authentication, node-red

I'm looking at the node-red authentication documentation (https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red) and it says that I can set up OAuth in my app and to use that as an auth strategy. Currently my app doesn't have OAuth and instead just adds JWT tokens to requests after a successful sign in by the user. I'm wondering if anyone knows if I can use those headers to authenticate node-red.

Any information on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Node-Red v1.1.2 release you can specify a custom token handler in your adminAuth configuration. This lets you use your own code to verify the custom  token node-red will use for authentication.

https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red#custom-authentication-tokens